# RSA cryptography?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I understand how RSA cryptosystem works; however, I am not sure how to apply it to answer these questions. Can someone explain please?

Let $N=3869$ and be equal to the product of two distinct, unknown, odd prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $(p−1)(q−1)$ is not divisible by $3$.

1. Show that there are exactly nine messages which are unchanged by RSA encryption using the public key $(N, 3)$.
2. Also explain how to find $p$ and $q$ if at least four of these messages are known.

I understand and have worked out how to show the first part.  However, I do not understand part 2. Can I get some help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very nice question that *feels* like it should be obvious, but which isn't (or at least wasn't to me). I blame it on the phrasing "at least four".

When you figure out the nine messages, three of them are trivially $0, -1, 1$. When you have four, you have to have at least one nontrivial message. It turns out this is the key. [Originally I thought I would have to be clever and combine multiple of these messages together in some way. But you don't].

Call the message $M$. Then we consider messages $M^3 \equiv M \pmod {pq}$. Then  we know that 
$$pq \mid M^3 - M = M(M+1)(M-1).$$
Since $M < pq$, we cannot have both $p,q$ dividing any of $M, M+1$ or $M-1$. (Since we're taking a nontrivial message, none of these are trivially $0$). Then taking
$$\begin{align}
&\gcd(M, N), \\
&\gcd(M+1, N), \\
&\gcd(M-1, N)
\end{align}$$
will yield $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation